# Issue styling formidable view

Tags: html, css, formidable

I'm trying to figure out how this plugin work with its view option, but I can't figure out how to remove the space between the to entries.
You can see my problem at [www.biketrading.dk](http://biketrading.dk/?page_id=24).
I hope someone can tell me what to do.

Comment: If you need to remove space between Såning and Plovning, set ``margin-bottom: 0;`` for the ``.entry-content-table`` selector. Otherwise, clarify the issue.

Comment: Sorry if my question is too thin, but it's the space between Såning and Plovning. Which file do I find it in? I'll guess it's not in the theme style.css?

Comment: @LarsLarsen See my answer as it should solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That spacing is defined by `margin-bottom` in your file : style.css?ver=3.9.1 . You will have to change both of these to the desired spacing.

**On line 1319:**

```
.entry-content table, .comment-content table {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.2857142857;
    margin-bottom: 24px;    <-------- HERE
}
```

**And on line 426:**

```
table {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-width: 1px 0 0 1px;
    margin-bottom: 24px;   <-------- HERE
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much it worked! I think my problem is that i don't know how to find the specific css style which is causing it through and browser (web developer tools). I can't find those line you refer to by myself :)

Comment: I use google chrome. If you right click and click "inspect element" on what you want to view it will open up the html code with the CSS on the side. It has references to the line numbers.

Comment: I have been using firefox for this where you can do the same, but I just can't find those code you provide but clearly is those I need to find. Maybe I should start using google chrome?

Comment: I personally like chromes tools better, it's all just a matter of opinion.

Comment: Lets see if I can learn a little bit more about those great tools so I don't need to disturb you with such questions. Again thank you for your help and time.